# php artisan - unknown table error on any command

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

For some reason whenever I run any `php artisan` command I get an error saying one of my tables doesn't exist. This is true, I'm starting on a new database.  What I can't figure out is why on earth artisan needs to use this table?  The error that shows up is:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
    'happylister.categories' doesn't exist (SQL: select *
    from `categories` order by `name` asc)

[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
    'happylister.categories' doesn't exist
```

I just can't figure out for the life of me where that query is coming from - even just using `php artisan` generates this error.  I first noticed this when I tried to run `php artisan migrate` to set up the tables, which of course failed. Then I noticed ALL `php artisan` commands fail.

So my question is: why would `php artisan` need a table specific to my app, given that normally you should be able to use `php artisan` on a clean database to set it up?

Comment: Probably some more code disclosure would help those people who might actually be able to help.

Comment: @St0fF I don't know what code artisan runs, so I don't know what code is relevant. Unfortunately the error gives me absolutely no context.  The full source is at https://github.com/nickcoad/happy-lister.  If you know what code is relevant to artisan I can post it in the question.

Comment: Perhaps it is an old mapping that is incorrect - have you done a search on your code to find that table name to see if it isn't showing up somewhere where it shouldn't be?

Comment: So it turns out service providers are all booted whenever any artisan command is run. Go figure.  That's where the problem lay - I had a service provider using the Categories table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Laracasts user very kindly helped me out with this answer:

> If you're referencing a model from a service provider and the
>   migrations have not been run, then you'll get that error. For some
>   reason Artisan commands like to load all the providers, even ones it
>   doesn't need.

Thank you to FetchTheDev over at the Laracasts forums.